# Snip & Sketch tool always flickers when using any annotation tools

Tags: windows, windows-10-v1909, snipping-tool

**tl;dr**: *Drawing any annotation in Windows 10's Snip & Sketch tool causes a screen flicker. Is there any workaround to this?*

---

Snip & Sketch is a gem in Windows 10 and it makes my life really easier. But the painless usage of it is only when I am using it in a simple matter of capturing some screen regions and pasting them to some program or saving them to disk.

The real pain starts when I am trying to use it with any of its annotation tools, i.e. Ballpoint pen, Pencil or Highlighter:

[image]

Any "real" annotation (i.e. left mouse click + move your mouse without releasing left mouse to draw some shape) always causes a very short, yet eyes blowing flicker of entire screen (a very fast image-to-black fade out + black-to-image fade in).

Only single clicks, without mouse moving or mouse moving after releasing mouse button does not cause this.

Is there anyone else who is experiencing the same problem? Is it a bug documented somewhere (I hope this is not a feature!)?

**Is there any possible workaround to this, to not make your eyes blow after you have to do a lot of screenshot + annotation operations in a short period of time?**

Comment: It is working fine here.  I suggest you upgrade your Video Driver and it this is a laptop, your Chipset driver as well.

Comment: What if you already have the latest driver?

Comment: Confirmed. Updating drivers to latest didn't resolve this issue. However, I am still reluctant to admit that this is something in Snip & Sketch itself, as it also works fine for me on other computers.

Comment: Same issue on my laptop at work. Not an issue at home computer. 

Comment: Did anyone resolve this? I'm seeing the same thing. MacBook Pro with Windows 10 on Bootcamp.

Comment: As you can see from the above comments the only resolution that we have figured out was to update / upgrade / reinstall video drivers. Worked in my case. There was no answer given so I could not accept it. I'd strongly suggest using "the other" drivers. Meaning, if you have a flickering effect on Windows drivers for your graphic card, try to replace them with manufacturer's ones. If otherwise -- then use native ones. Always the newest one. Sorry, no more idea than this.